# Filling object from a datareader

Tags: c#

I was asked a question in Interview. How will you fill your custom objects with data returned from a datareader.

My answer was using datareader.read(), creating instance of the custom object and setting properties with datareader values.

The interviewer was not pleased. He said if i have millions of records, then it will be very slow to fill these records using my approach. He asked me to suggest alternative way.

Is there any other way except this. Please comment.

Comment: Why would you request millions of rows? If you want to calculate some aggregated values, you should get the server to do the work and just return the result. If you need to display millions of rows to the user, you should use paging and fetch only the rows you need to display. Did the interviewer explain *why* he needs to fetch millions of rows? Did you ask him about this?

Comment: He said he doesnot want to loop around these records.

Answer (score 5):

Your approach is perfectly valid and used in many places. Now if you have millions of records you will probably won't like to fill an in-memory object anyway. But I guess it will depend on what you are going to do with the object. If the interviewer said that he doesn't want to loop around these records, then this defeats the purpose of a data reader.

Comment: > if you have millions of records you will probably won't ...
I agree!
I you have say thousands of records, then I prefer using the DataAdapter.Fill() over the datareader. 
I personally also like strongly typed datasets or even these ORM solutions:
http://www.llblgen.com/defaultgeneric.aspx
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate

Comment: whats the generic advantage of using DataAdapter? DataAdapter just uses a DataReader behind the scenes anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Did you suggest storing the business objects in some kind of in memory data structure? If so, maybe the interviewer was interested in a solution where objects are instantiated within a generator method and returned to the consumer using `yield return`?

Comment: Output has to be a collection containing all these values. IS it possible using yield return?

Comment: Generally, you want to close your connection to the database as soon as you can.  Using a generator can only increase the amount of time that the connection remains open.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the scenario - there aren't enough requirements there, but some thoughts:

- iterator block (`yield return`) avoids having to buffer all the data
- if you were writing specific C# code per type, then that is fine - but you shouldn't use (raw) reflection if performance is critical; a dynamic method (`ILGenerator` etc, or `Expression`), or something like HyperDescriptor can take the sting out of reflection
- if they want a collection, the collection could *itself* be lazy loaded as you consume it, but you won't be able to get the `Count` in advance unless your TSQL returns this first
- He might be arguing that a constructor might be quicker than using individual properties, but frankly I suspect he hasn't profiled it; there will rarely be a *significant* difference here between setting properties vs fields (inside the ctor). In fact, I'm preparing a blog post on that exact subject as I write...

Comment: but using `yield` will keep that data connection open for a (potential) long time

Comment: It is a trade off, of course ;-p Lots of memory vs an open connection. Like I said, it depends on the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

My immediate answer to the question, "How do you is fill your custom objects with data returned from a `DataReader`?" is, "By using composition."  Apparently the interviewer thought he was asking a different and much less interesting question.